# iOS twitter integration using OAuth like in Instagram

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am implementing login with twitter.I want to allow user to login from settings and if settings account is not configured, then login with web view. Following is the module i use to add account in settings.

```
 ACAccount *newAccount = [[ACAccount alloc]initWithAccountType:accountType];
            ACAccountCredential *credentials = [[ACAccountCredential alloc]initWithOAuthToken:@"" tokenSecret:@""];
            [newAccount setCredential:credentials];
            [accountStore saveAccount:newAccount withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                if ( success) {
                    NSLog(@"Success");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Fail");
                }
            }];
```

I have tried to login using oAuth by getting access token but could not find proper solution.
My OAuth Code as below

```
twitterURL = @"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token" ;
        NSMutableURLRequest* postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:twitterURL]];
        [postRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
        NSArray * parameterArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", @"x_auth_mode", [@"client_auth" urlEncode]],
                                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", @"x_auth_password", [TWITTER_PASSWORD urlEncode]],
                                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", @"x_auth_username", [TWITTER_USERNAME urlEncode]],
                                    nil];
        [postRequest setHTTPBody:[[parameterArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postRequest addValue:self.authorizationHeader
           forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

And the authorization header is as below

```
 NSArray * keysAndValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=\"%@\"", @"oauth_nonce", [self.nonce urlEncode]],
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=\"%@\"", @"oauth_signature_method", [@"HMAC-SHA1" urlEncode]],
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=\"%@\"", @"oauth_timestamp", [self.timestamp urlEncode]],
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=\"%@\"", @"oauth_consumer_key", [TWITTERAPIKEY urlEncode]],
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=\"%@\"", @"oauth_signature", [self.signature urlEncode]],
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=\"%@\"", @"oauth_version", [@"1.0" urlEncode]],
                                   nil];
        keysAndValues = [keysAndValues arrayByAddingObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=\"%@\"", @"oauth_token", [self.token urlEncode]]];
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OAuth %@", [keysAndValues componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
```

While making request using above code of OAuth it gives me **"401 Error"**.

Kindly help me to solve the problem.